# Updating an administrative Outlook Client installation with SP1 for CRM 2013

Tags: outlook, windows-installer, crm

Bear with me here because this may be a tricky question.

I have a slipstreamed installation packages for the CRM 2013 Outlook Client. Up until now I have only needed the 32bit client version so that's all I prepared. The package is updated with SP1 and SP1 UR2.

A new set of circumstances brought up the need for deploying the 64bit client as well (not on the same PC naturally). Put aside any advice about not using Office 64bit and the fact that Microsoft recommends against it (I already tried speaking against it to no avail).
When trying to use the same methods as the 32bit client I attempt to go through the following steps:

1. Extract:

   - CRM2013-Client-ENU-amd64.exe (base)
   - CRM2013-Client-KB2941390-ENU-amd64.exe (client SP1)
   - CRM2013-Client-KB2963850-ENU-amd64.exe (client SP1 UR2)
   - CRM2013-Mui-KB2941390-ENU-amd64.exe (English MUI SP1)
   - CRM2013-Mui-KB2963850-ENU-amd64.exe (English MUI SP1 UR2)
2. Update Client.msi to SP1.
3. Update Client.msi to SP1 UR2.
4. Update MUISetup_1033_amd64.msi to SP1.
5. Update MUISetup_1033_amd64.msi to SP1 UR2.

Steps 1-3 work just fine but then step 4 fails with the following error.

> Source file not found:
>   C:\Temp\Base\Server\LangPacks\1033\sql\6.0\Metadata\Xml\Account.xml. Verify that the file exists and that you can access it.

Indeed that folder does not exist because I am attempting to patch the client installation and not the server. The installation appears to be complaining about missing server folders that should not even exist in a client.

Trying to search for optional installation flags or parameters hasn't helped. Even running through a verbose log file of the installation brought no enlightenment about any possible options.

Solutions I would rather not implement:

- Manually creating the missing folder structure and files to avoid this error. There are hundreds of files in the missing folder structure.
- Apply the full English language pack to the base installation folder. Might work but complicates the solution and takes me to the land of unsupported installations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems like there's no magic solution to this.

I ended up exploring the method of extracting the full MUI pack on top of the Client folder. The reason I'm ok with this is because a folder comparison of the MUI folder and the corresponding folders in the Client folder were identical. Even the MSI is identical. The only difference was the absence of the Server folder in the Client package.

So, if anyone else comes across this issue, the solution is this:

1. Extract (to separate folders):

   - CRM2013-Client-ENU-amd64.exe (base)
   - CRM2013-Client-KB2941390-ENU-amd64.exe (client SP1)
   - CRM2013-Client-KB2963850-ENU-amd64.exe (client SP1 UR2)
   - CRM2013-Mui-KB2941390-ENU-amd64.exe (English MUI SP1)
   - CRM2013-Mui-KB2963850-ENU-amd64.exe (English MUI SP1 UR2)
2. Extract CRM2013-Mui-ENU-amd64.exe into the same folder where you previously extracted CRM2013-Client-ENU-amd64.exe. This did not bring up any overwrite files warnings for me but I cannot guarantee that won't happen for anyone else.
3. Update Client.msi to 6.0.0.809 (from the pre-release 6.0.0.302 build). This is an easy to miss step but is absolutely required for a stable installation later. In the base client extracted folder there is a Windows Installer patch package called Client_KB2888948_amd64_1033.msp. You must apply this to Client.msi and then delete Client_KB2888948_amd64_1033.msp. If you do not perform these two steps, the installation bootstrap will apply this patch **AFTER** everything else has been installed and revert many files back to 6.0.0.809 (RTM).
4. Update Client.msi to SP1.
5. Update Client.msi to SP1 UR2.
6. Update MUISetup_1033_amd64.msi to SP1.
7. Update MUISetup_1033_amd64.msi to SP1 UR2.
8. Clean up (to reduce 254 MiB from the installation package):

   - Under the base installation folder, delete the *Update* folder. See step 3 above for details about this.
   - Under the base installation folder, delete the *sql* folder. This is not used by installations of build 6.0.0.809 and above and is only used by build 6.0.0.302 which is a pre-release CRM build Microsoft latched on to. As we are patching the base installation to 6.0.0.809 we do not need that folder any more.
   - Under the base installation folder, delete the *Server* folder. This was only added so the MUI patching process would not fail but is not required by the client installation.

Finally, some command tidbits you may require for the above steps.

Extracting an installation package to a folder:

> CRM2013-Client-ENU-amd64.exe /extract:"C:\Temp\Base"

Updating an MSI package with a matching MSP patch package:

> msiexec /a C:\Temp\Base\Client.msi /p C:\Temp\SP1\Client_KB2941390_amd64_1033.msp /qb

I hope this helps someone in the future.